# How to convert a Decimal to Number(with decimal numbers) in Python

Tags: python

Suppose, I have a decimal expansion 2.896. I want to convert it to something like 2896. How can I achieve this in Python?

Comment: Multiply by 1000?

Comment: Please, check [ask].

Comment: It will be in a loop-loop. So multiplying every single time... That won't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this;

```
n = 2.896
n1 = int(str(n).replace(".",""))
```